# How to make a photo grouping app in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I want to make a photo grouping app in Xcode.
I use storyboard and it include two view controller.
And connect this two VC with navigation bar.
I add images in supporting file.(Eg. Friend1.jpg, Friend2.jpg, Family1.jpg, Family2.jpg)

In VC1, there are three button, friend,family and co-worker.
In VC2, there is a image view to show images.

When i press friend button in VC1, the image view in VC2 show Friend1.jpg
Then, i slide from left to right, it show Friend2.jpg

Such like that, when i press family button in VC1, the image view in VC2 show Family1.jpg
Then, i slide from left to right, it show Family2.jpg

Please, give me advices of how can i start it easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a UICollectionView for this:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html

> The UICollectionView class manages an ordered collection of data items
>   and presents them using customizable layouts. Collection views provide
>   the same general function as table views except that a collection view
>   is able to support more than just single-column layouts. Collection
>   views support customizable layouts that can be used to implement
>   multi-column grids, tiled layouts, circular layouts, and many more.
>   You can even change the layout of a collection view dynamically if you
>   want.

Check out Apples documentation or Google for tutorials, e.g:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

Comment: Thanks you. You give me good idea of how to start it. I appreciate your guide line and thanks again. It save my learning time.